# AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values on Jetson Nano with TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt

I am trying to run Inference on my Jetson Nano with TensorRT, but this Error keeps popping up. I dont really work with `.pb` model rather than `.h5` models thats why I am converting my Model to `.pb` from `.h5`.

I am using this script to convert my model to a tensorrt model, its a modification of the nvidia docs scripts, but more or less the same : [Nvidia Docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

model_dir = 'fc_medium'

tf_model_dir = 'final_vitis/float/'+ model_dir+'.h5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(tf_model_dir)

input_saved_model_dir = 'final_jetson/'+ model_dir+'/tf/'
os.makedirs(input_saved_model_dir, exist_ok=True)

tf.saved_model.save(model,input_saved_model_dir)


output_saved_model_dir = 'final_jetson/'+ model_dir+'/tf_trt/'
os.makedirs(output_saved_model_dir, exist_ok=True)


from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(input_saved_model_dir=input_saved_model_dir)
converter.convert()
converter.save(output_saved_model_dir)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_jetson_tensorRT.py", line 21, in <module>
    converter.convert()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/compiler/tensorrt/trt_convert.py", line 1216, in convert
    self._input_saved_model_tags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 900, in load
    result = load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 939, in load_internal
    ckpt_options, options, filters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 166, in __init__
    self._restore_checkpoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 495, in _restore_checkpoint
    load_status.assert_existing_objects_matched()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 831, in assert_existing_objects_matched
    (list(unused_python_objects),))
AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [<tf.Variable 'dense_4_m/bias/v:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_3_m/bias/m:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1_m/kernel/m:0' shape=(784, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1_m/kernel/v:0' shape=(784, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_4_m/bias/m:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_3_m/kernel/v:0' shape=(128, 128) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_2_m/kernel/m:0' shape=(256, 128) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1_m/bias/v:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_2_m/bias/m:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_3_m/bias/v:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_4_m/kernel/m:0' shape=(128, 10) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_2_m/kernel/v:0' shape=(256, 128) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_3_m/kernel/m:0' shape=(128, 128) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_4_m/kernel/v:0' shape=(128, 10) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1_m/bias/m:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_2_m/bias/v:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>]
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-0.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-0.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-2.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).layer_with_weights-3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-0.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-0.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-2.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).layer_with_weights-3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem while using **Nvidia's Docker** containers.

This issue was resolved by changing the **Docker** image I was using.

A few **Docker** images were compatible with the Jetson Nano release I had.

In my case, this image resolved the problem: `nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-tensorflow:r32.6.1-tf2.5-py3`

If you aren't utilising **Docker** images, you could experiment with them to find the best combination of software packages and then reproduce that.